# Is there a simple command line UPnP AV Control Point?

Tags: command-line, dlna, upnp

I am looking to implement a Glorified Internet Picture Frame at work. The goal is to show a 4k picture on our wonderful 4k television, with all pixels intact, from a network-accessible source which is on the company network. I don't want the pictures go through the Internet. Ideally, i want to tell the television when to update the picture, not just periodically refresh the image shown.

The closest thing i've come to success is using UPnP AV. Showing the same picture with the internal web browser will amazingly enough use only half the pixels from the image and renders the rest through anti-aliasing.

I have managed to install MiniDLNA (ReadyDLNA), which is a bit slow to get discovered but works for now. But: i've only managed to get the picture on the television using BubbleUPnP on my Android tablet. This is neither viable, nor elegant.

What i want is to automate the thing and control the UPnP MediaRenderer using a scriptable command-line-able UPnP Control Point.

Is there something comparable to curl or netcat in simplicity, which will simply throw a picture at a picture frame? I don't care if the UPnP MediaServer bit is thrown in, as long as it works and i can script it. I don't need support for audio or video, which probably necessitates callbacks and status updates and whatnots. Fire and forget is the path to profit.

I've found one UPnP IGD client, which doesn't solve the problem, one Ruby library and one Perl library, but they seem overly complicated to solve this superficially simple issue.

I acknowledge that i might have misunderstood the UPnP architecture completely and that the Control Point *has* to be alive at all times or the connection will break. In that case, Fire and Forget is not the path to profit and the CP needs to be a daemon which can receive input somehow. I don't mind some enlightenment if it's polite :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This software seems to be doing the job for you.

https://github.com/xat/dlnacast

Actualy the media library has to be alive all the time. Control point can be used like fire and forget. But there are different solutions.